# My PHP/HTML Radio Button Form in a loop is not working. Why?

Tags: php, html, forms, radio-button, html-select

```
<?php

   $_SESSION['ValueSelected'] = $_POST['subject'];

   $num=1;
   $opt = array();

    for($row=1; $row<=65; $row++)
         {
           if($Set_Details[0][$row - 1] == $userinID)    
        {
          echo '<input type="radio" name="subject" value="$opt[$num]"> ' . $Set_Details[1][$row-1] . ' - '. $Set_Details[3][$row-1] . '<br>';
              $num++;
       }
     }   
?>
```

Let me explain my code. $Set_Details is a double dimensional array and it is working without any problems. Based on the number of subjects a teacher has, that many radio buttons will be generated. Each of them has a common name but different values. Each of the subjects displayed can be selected through a radio button. Now, I want to send the selected option to another page. How should I go about doing this? Without:

```
$_SESSION['ValueSelected'] = $_POST['subject'];
```

The program runs normally. Only when I put this line, errors are generated. It says:

```
Notice: Undefined index: subject in C:\xampp\htdocs\GradingPortal\FacultyIndex.php on line 98
```

Comment: You are missing `session_start();` on top after the `<?php` tag ?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$_SESSION['ValueSelected'] = isset($_POST['subject']);
```

or try this

```
$_SESSION['ValueSelected'] = @$_POST['subject'];
```

Comment: its only for avoid the warning message.

Answer (score 0):

If you run the query with a GET request (i.e. just load the page) you will get an error because the `$_POST` variable would not be sent. Doing the following will remove the debug message but may not solve logical issues you may have

```
$_SESSION['ValueSelected'] = (isset($_POST['subject'])) ? $_POST['subject'] : null;
```